# I installed webpack and uninstalled it, and now my angular2 app won't launch anymore

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, webpack

Here's my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "app=thing",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.10.1",
    "npm": "3.10.7"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "heroku-postbuild": "typings install && ng build",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.23",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.2.30",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.14",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2",
    "typings": "1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30"
  }
}
```

---

I installed webpack using "npm install webpack" and then I uninstalled it using "npm uninstall webpack", now I my angular2 server won't start, because of a "WebpackOptionsValidationError"

Here's what I tried so far:

1) Trashing the node_modules folder and reinstalling all the packages
2) git reset --hard (this obviously doesn't work cause node_modules isn't in the repo)
3) Downloading the repo again and running npm install --save, and then trying to start the server, and that doesn't work either. 
4) Uninstalling all the globally installed node packages on my system.

I'm totally baffled. Any ideas? It's like webpack is still installed somehow... :S

I'm starting the server like this:

```
ng serve --proxy proxy.conf.json
```

---

```
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'tslint'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: {
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           tslint: ...
         }
       })
     }
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'preLoaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, loaders?, noParse?, rules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }
   Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
 - configuration.node.global should be a boolean.
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'root'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache? }
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
    at webpack (/Users/dud/Work/app-thing/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:16:9)
    at Class.exports.default.Task.extend.run (/Users/dud/Work/app-thing/client/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/serve-webpack.js:23:27)
    at /Users/dud/Work/app-thing/client/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/serve.js:84:26
    at tryCatch (/Users/dud/Work/app-thing/client/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/lib/es6-promise/-internal.js:195:12)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/dud/Work/app-thing/client/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/lib/es6-promise/-internal.js:210:13)
    at publish (/Users/dud/Work/app-thing/client/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/lib/es6-promise/-internal.js:178:7)
    at flush (/Users/dud/Work/app-thing/client/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/lib/es6-promise/asap.js:94:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: What do you run to start the app?

Comment: `ng serve --proxy proxy.conf.json`

Comment: What is the `ng` command?

Comment: what is the result of ng --version ?

Comment: `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15
node: 5.10.1
os: darwin x64`

Answer (score 1):

Updating the package.json to use angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.15 fixed it.